# Custom heatmap 3D texture

Tags: texturing, interpolation

I have a 3D model constructed from photogrammetry. I would like to colorize this based on custom values on some vertices, and interpolate a heatmap for the rest of the mesh based on these values. I would like to either assign a max/min value to the vertices from which a color ramp is generated or do this outside of Blender and give the vertices RGB values from which the rest of the texture is interpolated.

Does anyone have a workflow or ideas on how this may be achieved?

Edit: I managed to acomplish this using the pyvista interpolate tool https://docs.pyvista.org/examples/01-filter/interpolate.html

Comment: You may be able to do this with vertex groups and then plugging them into a colour ramp from the shader editor. Let me test this for you, will give complete answer below soon.

Comment: Hmmm, it seems like you can't currently import the weights from vertex groups into the shader editor natively, but there is an addon to do it. https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/Mkfbbc/

Answer (score 0):

I quite didn't understand the *meaning* of your **Heat map** so I created a *not-so-complex* **procedural material**, which would consist of **3-4 nodes** based on *your* **heat map**.

> 1] Depth Map : This map is based on height, if u want this kind of material then use the top three nodes
>
> nodes [image: Heat map based on height]

> 2] Fake Heat Map : This is a fake heat map based on distance from the
> camera, a very common filter.
>
> [image: Heat map based on distance from camera]

> Ahh! I nearly forgot, you can also use the layer weight node to get
> the faces facing the camera. Like This :
>
> [image: Heat map base on Facing]

Comment: Feel **free** to play with the _values_